# Gembox Excel send directly to Printer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, gembox-spreadsheet

I have made a web application where i can write out reports in Excel, using the Gemboxs features.

Using this Example: [Gembox Example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-library/601)

Now i would like to send it directly to the Printer, which is connected to the server the web application is running on.

The web application is made in .Net Mvc.

```
ef.Save("Hello World.xlsx"); // Where "ef" is The ExcelFile.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ef.Print();

```
 // Print to default printer using default options
 this.ef.Print();
```

Found on the 
[Gembox documentation](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-print-excel/451)